# Speed of a point on a concentric disk setup

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, rotational-kinematics

I have been really solving this question that my friend and I had thought of while discussing about speed of light. Imagine there is a set-up where there is a light source that is surrounded by a hallow disc with a radius $r$ that has a hole at a point. Again the disc and the light source are surrounded by another bigger disc that has a very great radius $R$( compared to the inner disc,$R >> r$, in order of $10^9$) . The diagram somehow looks like this:

[image]

The inner disc starts to rotate counter-clockwise such that point $A$ has tangential speed $v_A = \frac{c}{2}$. The light beam emitting from the light source can only travel through the hole in the inner disc. Lets denote two points $A$ and $B$ on the inner disc and the outer disc respectively, where the light beam crosses the discs. The time it takes for point $A$ to complete one full rotation is $$t = \frac{2\pi r}{v_A}$$  where $v_A = \frac{c}{2}$

Now, what I can't seem to figure out is the speed at which point $B$ rotates and the time it takes point $B$ to complete one full rotation. How can I find those?

Answer (score 1):

It would take the same time as it took with A, so
 $v_b=\frac{2\pi R}{t}$

$t=\frac{2\pi r}{v}$

$ v= c/2$

Note that if $R$ is big enough, it may seem as if the point $B$ is travelling faster than light, it is. But the fact is that no physical object is really travelling faster than light.

Comment: I think this is correct, why -1? +1. The spot in B can travel faster than c, but that spot cannot be used to transfer information.

Comment: Could somebody explain the downvote?

Comment: Can this scenario be tested in real life? What would be the speed of point B?